# Parsing XML inner messages list using Python

Tags: python, xml, list, parsing

I am trying to parse the following messages and store them in a list using python.
How can I store the messages in a list?

I reached the id and the language by the following code, but I need to find the messages.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getiterator()
print (root[0].attrib)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><author id="1aa8c430-853b-4bbc-b784-df4c88264ccd" lang="en">
    <document><![CDATA[@username bahaha! unfortunately i'm not a tshirt person      ]]></document>
    <document><![CDATA[Mercy reunion at Olive Garden #traditions :)     ]]></document>
    <document><![CDATA[After 3 months of beating my head against a wall over this persuasion, I've finally had my "aha!" moment!! #progress! #improvement!      ]]></document>
</author>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("your_file.xml")
out = [d.text for d in tree.iter("document")]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    "@username bahaha! unfortunately i'm not a tshirt person      ",
    "Mercy reunion at Olive Garden #traditions :)     ",
    'After 3 months of beating my head against a wall over this persuasion, I\'ve finally had my "aha!" moment!! #progress! #improvement!      ',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

First get the author tag from your root element:

```
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getiterator()
author = root[0]
```

Then the language from the author tag's attrib:

```
author['lang']
```

...and the id:

```
author['id']
```

If you are storing the content of the author tag, you could create a dictionary to store the content of each author:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getiterator()
```

## Iterate over the `root` elements and get the author tags

```
authors = []

for root in root:
    author = root.get('author')
    authors.append(author)
```

## Get the language and id from the author tag

```
authors = {author['lang']:author['id'] for author in authors}
```

## Iterate over the `authors` dictionary and print out the content

```
print(authors)
```

or

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filename)

root = tree.getiterator()
author = root[0]
lang = root.find('lang')
id = root.find('id')

print(author,lang,id)
```